# Strip symbols for iPhone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, symbols, strip

What are the settings in Xcode to strip symbols for an iphone application?

I use these settings in Xcode but still see classnames and their methods in 
the executable using a binary file editor.

Deployment:

1) Deployment Post processing(checked)

2) Strip Debug Symbols During Copy(checked)

3) Strip Linked Product(checked)

4) Use Separate Strip(checked)

Linking:

5) Dead Code Stripping(checked)

GCC 4.0 - Code Generation

6) Generate Debug Symbols(NOT checked)

Answer (score 9):

Objective-C class and method information can't be stripped - it is necessary for execution.  Best you can do is come up with some kind of obfuscation, if you want.

Answer (score 4):

I did it.

I only checked following three settings, other setting is irrelevant.

1) Deployment Postprocessing (checked)

3) Strip Linked Product (checked)

4) Use Separate Strip (checked)

[image]

Of course, you need should check "Distribution" version in schema editor.
[image]

Then clean!!! and build.

I'v also confirmed that "strip" command is called by Xcode:
Show log navigator, select Build .... release, at the bottom,  i found progress description:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aaaaa-dytaamkvztdwfreoqteyeijwqdcu/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/aaaaa.app/aaaaa
```

[image]

Finally, I'v checked the result by "nm" command to final product file,

`nm -a /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aaaaa-dytaamkvztdwfreoqteyeijwqdcu/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/aaaaa.app/aaaaa`

All function name of current app is really stripped. Such as following function name :

000b0a00 t _pj_ioqueue_create

00092ae4 t ___destroy_helper_block_200

00092af8 t ___68-[MyClass myMethod:param2]_block_invoke_21782

Note: objective-C method and property name string are still produced to app file, but that is not symbol name for OS loader, they are just meta data of objective-C class.

Comment: Where do I find the use separate strip build setting?

Comment: In build settings

Comment: I can find deployment post-processing and strip linked product but I can't find use separate strip in build settings

Comment: I am not sure now because I'am not working on Xcode recently, but it is is maybe because Postprocessing is not enabled?

Comment: that's right, deployment post-processing should be on for strip style to work.