# How to avoid symbols and source paths in iOS binary?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, symbols

When I compile the *release* version of my iOS app (based on standard Apple supplied iOS app template), look into the resulting executable binary, I see all sorts of symbols and even local cpp source and header paths in there. I'm really stumped why this is (I haven't enabled RTTI*). Especially the source file paths make me feel uncomfortable sending this app across the globe (why should everyone be able to see the directory layout of my development machine?).

Here's are two (randomly picked, moderated) excerpts:

`TS/../ACTORS/CActorCanvasCharPart.cpplastMeshcapVerticesOFF BOUNDSupload VERTICES: %d
20CActorCanvasCharPartgrassscrub/Volumes/Data/iOS_projects/code/MyAppName_proj/MyAppName/source/STATES/GAMES/2/CStateGame2_grass.cppbaseShadowmowerstartmowerloopmowermowerCharcutGrassChargrassStuffgrassParticles/Volumes/Data/iOS_projects/code/MyAppName_proj/MyAppName/source/STATES/GAMES/2/CStateGame2_grass.h17CStateGame2_grasssinwriteStroke/Volumes/Data/iOS_projects/code/MyAppName_proj/MyAppName/source/STATES/GAMES/2/CStateGame2_flowers.hflowerBedsandTrailclickstart3inplace2sandDrag/Volumes/Data/iOS_projects/code/MyAppName_proj/MyAppName/source/STATES/GAMES/2/CStateGame`

And here are a lot of symbols for self-defined types and structs:

`CAssetMgr="_vptr$CMgrBase"^^?"pMain"^{CMain}"inited"B"curveCount"S"curveSpecs"^{CCurveSpec}"gameSpecs"[23{CGameStateSpec="header"{SpecDiskHeader="type"i"version"S}"gameID"C"backgroundColor"{CRGBAcolorf="r"f"g"f"b"f"a"f}"clickPointColor"{CRGBAcolorf="r"f"g"f"b"f"a"f}"clickPointIconColor"{CRGBAcolorf="r"f"g"f"b"f"a"f}"hintColor"{CRGBAcolorf="r"f"g"f"b"f"a"f}}]"currentFont"^{CCharset}"userCharParts"^^{CCharPart}"words"{CDataSet<CName4,CCharArray>="_vptr$CObjectBase"^^?"pMain"^{CMain}"count"i"data"*"dataSize"l}"sets"{CDataSet<CName16,CCharArray>="_vptr$CObjectBase"^^?"pMain"^{CMain}"count"i"data"*"dataSize"l`

Can this be avoided, how?

*UPDATE: I just found out that RTTI is on by default. So I cleaned the target, disabled RTTI (GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI = NO) and recompiled. I still see a lot of symbols and source paths in the binary.

UPDATE 2: I checked a few other apps from the app store, and many of them also have their source file paths show up. Pretty scary, if you ask me:

`Joined Up Lite

/Users/lloydy/Documents/Development/iPhone/ABC Joined Up/main.m

/Users/lloydy/Documents/Development/iPhone/ABC Joined Up/Classes/SettingsView.m`

`Crayon Physics

/Users/smproot/Desktop/unzip/CrayonPhysics/v104/Classes/crayon/src/ceng/gameutils/killspriteslowly/killspriteslowly.cpp

/Users/smproot/Desktop/unzip/CrayonPhysics/v104/Classes/crayon/src/ceng/tasks/task/sdl/mixer/ctaskaudiosdlmixer.cpp`

`Wall Times

/Users/fred/_WORK/ZDNDRP/WallTimes/main.m

/Users/fred/_WORK/ZDNDRP/WallTimes/Classes/SystemCategories.m`

`Jumbo Calculator

/Users/Christopher/Documents/Development/JumboCalculator 1.0.3/main.m

/Users/Christopher/Documents/Development/JumboCalculator 1.0.3/Classes/CalculatorFaceViewController.m`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730478/strip-symbols-for-iphone-application

Comment: I've tried all the configuration options listed there, but to no avail: lots of CPP symbols and *lots* of file paths. Too bad, it looked promising...

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730478/strip-symbols-for-iphone-application/18226723#18226723

Answer (score 9):

The file paths are most likely from assert macros which stringify `__FILE__` as part of their failure message. iOS's implementation of `assert(3)` does this, as do the `NSAssert` macros.

You can remove asserts in release builds by defining `NDEBUG` (for the C asserts) and `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` (for NSAsserts).

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode set Deployment Prostprocessing to Yes in order to trigger Xcode to call the strip command during build process. Then you don't see any source path via nm -a.

However, I still see the source paths of some m files via the strings command :/

Comment: This helped me to strip most of paths.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was setting `Generate Debug Symbols` to `No` for release builds. This is under the `Apple LLVM 7.0 - Code Generation` in Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

Have ticked the strip debug symbols in the build settings? You can do this (or not) depending on the configuration (build/release). Also you can look into [Objective-C Code Obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727327/objective-c-code-obfuscation) (which is long winded). From what I gather, you cannot completely remove objective-c information as all method calls are done dynamically, so the library has to have information about your classes/method names in order to function. A useful tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393690/tips-or-tools-for-obfuscating-objective-c-binary).

If you have c++ code then you can use the [gcc strip utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413171/what-is-strip-gcc-application-used-for), although I'm not sure how it like Objetive-C++, if it doesn't you could compile all you cpp into a lib, strip that and link against it in your iOS project.

Comment: Yes, it's on for the release configuration.

Comment: I think you're right for objC, but there's only a fraction of Objective-C in this app. It's mostly straight cpp, but some files are .mm's.